# How reimport a package in UDK with command line?

Tags: udk

sometimes ago, I saw a command to re-import a UDK package content without opening the UDK Editor.
(Especially, it was used for reimporting a Flash package in a scaleform tutorial, but it doesn't matter now )

It's very useful, because every time I change my .swf file, I should open the heavy UDK and just press re-import.

So, can anyone give me that solution again  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution For packages containing `.swf files` [here](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/ScaleformImport.html#gfximport%20Commandlet) :

> **gfximport Commandlet**
>
> To improve iteration time, the gfximport commandlet, run from your Unreal Engine 3 executable (e.g UDKLift.exe) allows for content importing and reimporting without loading Unreal Editor. The commandlet assumes that content has been arranged in the manner described above.
>
> In order to import a file, you must run gfximport commandlet while specifying relative paths to all of the .SWF files within the GameDir\Flash directory that you wish to import separated by spaces.

`UDKLift.exe gfximport [path_1] [path_2] [path_3]`

> In order to re-import files that are already imported into UE3, simply run the commandlet with no arguments.

`UDKLift.exe gfximport`

> The commandlet will reimport all the SwfMovies for which the .SWF file on disk is newer than the one imported.
>
> Example:
>
> Suppose you want to import these files.
>
> ```
> C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\UDKGame\Flash\UI\MainMenu.swf
> C:\UDK\UDK-2010-07\UDKGame\Flash\UI\Resources.swf
> ```
>
> You would execute the following command:

`UDKLift.exe gfximport UI/MainMenu.swf UI/Resources.swf`

> They will be imported into the UI package as SwfMovie'UI.MainMenu' and SwfMovie'UI.Resources'. The package will be saved as GameDir\Content\GFx\UI.upk.